# Angular2 When click outide div, it should be close

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

Here the code, when i cliktoshow method then it shows the div. When i click outide of that div it has to hides itself.

```js
      public hideElement: boolean = false;   

       clicktoshow()
       {
           this.organizedetailsshow = false;
           if (this.hideElement) {
           this.hideElement = false;
      }
     else {
         this.hideElement = true;
    }
    } 
    
    outsidehide(e)
         {
           console.log("event",e)
           if(this != $("#myDiv")[0]) {
             this.hideElement = false;
           }
         }(e)
         {
           console.log("event",e)
           if(this != $("#myDiv")[0]) {
             this.hideElement = false;
           }
         }
```

```html
  <div>
    <div>
    <button (click)= "clicktoshow()">  Click to show  button </button>
    <div !hideElement (click)=outsidehide($event)> 
         hi 
      </div>
                 <p> Hi hello </p>
  </div>
```

Here the code, when i cliktoshow method then it shows the div. When i click outide that div it has to hides itself.

Comment: You can create Directive for that. please visit [this link](https://christianliebel.com/2016/05/angular-2-a-simple-click-outside-directive/) or directly use this [npm package](https://github.com/chliebel/angular2-click-outside).

Comment: Can you show more code? What does the show code look like? What does the html look like?

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="background-color:red;width:50px;height:50px" *ngIf="isDivHide" id="testBox"> Testing </span>

<button (click)="bounce()" id="btn"> Bounce me </button>
```

If the above is your html and `MyAnimation` is your corresponding component then you can configure your component like this,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-anim',
    templateUrl: 'App/Animation/animation.html',
    host: {
        '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
    }
})

export class MyAnimation {
    animationService = null;

    isDivHide = false;

    onClick = function (event) {
        if (!$(event.target).is($('#testBox') ) && !$(event.target).is($('#btn')) ){ 
            // Hide the test box
            this.isDivHide = false;
        }
    }

    bounce = function () {
        this.isDivHide = true;
        }

    constructor() {
        this.isDivHide = false;
    }
}
```

**Explanation**

```
host: {
    '(document:click)': 'onClick($event)',
}
```

This will bind the click event of your `document` to `onClick()` function.

So, this function will fire every time when you click on your document. So be careful to use this function.

```
onClick = function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).is($('#testBox') ) && !$(event.target).is($('#btn')) ){ 
        // Hide the test box
        this.isDivHide = false;
    }
}
```

Here you are checking whether the clicked element is your testBox or the button. If no then hide your test box.

That's all !!!

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'll try this one.

Comment: I want to click the div inside, but it hides when i click inside div

Answer (score 0):

Because your scenario is to hide an element and not to manipulate the DOM structure, you can create an attribute directive to be applied to your `<div>`.

Find bellow one solution:

**Directive**

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[showMe]'
})
export class ShowMeDirective {

  private _show: boolean;

  /**
   * Emmit changes in 'showMe'.
   * @type {EventEmitter}
   */
  @Output('showMeChange')
  public showChange = new EventEmitter();

  /**
   * Called when the 'showMe' expression changes.
   * @param show Whether to show or hide the element.
   */
  @Input('showMe')
  public set show(show: boolean) {
    this.elRef.nativeElement.style.display = show ? null : 'none';
    this._show = show;
  }

  /**
   * Get whether the element is visible.
   * @returns {boolean}
   */
  public get show() {
    return this._show;
  }

  /**
   * Ctor.
   * @param elRef References the element
   */
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  /**
   * Stop propagating click event for current element.
   * @param $event Event arguments
   */
  @HostListener('click', ['$event'])
  public onElementClick($event) {
    $event.stopPropagation();
  }

  /**
   * When the document is clicked then the element is hidden.
   */
  @HostListener('document:click')
  public onDocumentClick() {
    if (this.show !== false) {
      this.show = false;
      this.showChange.emit(false);
    }
  }
}
```

**Usage**

```
<div [(showMe)]="show" style="line-height: 50px; font-weight: bold;">
  Contents of DIV
</div>

<p>DIV is visible: {{ show }}</p>
<br/>

<button (click)="show = true; $event.stopPropagation();" type="button">Show DIV</button>
```

`show` is initially set to a value (eg: `show = false`).

**Explanation**

The `showMe` directive defines an input (annotated with @Input) which is the directive attribute itself `showMe`. This allow to pass this value also from the outside and react accordingly. Therefore this is a setter which sets the `style.display` value and triggers a change event.

The `showMe` directive defines also an output (annotated with @Output) which is called `showMeChange`. This is in order to reflect the changes in the model, so that the component which uses the directive will have its property changed accordingly.

The `showMe` directive subscribe to the `click` event of the element on which it is applied using `@HostListener('click', ['$event'])`. Therefore when is clicked the event is not propagating so that it will not be intercepted by `document.click` handler.

The `showMe` directive subscribe to the `document.click` event in order to render the element invisible.

The `<button>` handles the `click` event but he is also preventing the `click` from bubbling to other elements by doing `$event.stopPropagation();`.

Because `showMe` directive defines `showMe` input and `showMeChange` output it can be written as `<div [showMe]="show" (showMeChange)="show = $event;">`. But it can also be written as `<div [(showMe)]="show">` (banana-in-a-box style).

Therefore you can manipulate the visibility from within the directive but also from outside of directive thus passing data back and forth.

**NOTE:** the following `if` code prevents firing the event when the value was not changed from within the directive:

```
  public onDocumentClick() {
    if (this.show !== false) {
      this.show = false;
      this.showChange.emit(false);
    }
  }
```